# Aprilaire 500 bypass humidifier problem with Carrier Infiniti 59TN6 96% furnace NOT turning on blower fan

Tags: electrical, wiring

New Carrier Infinity HVAC system installed. Problem is, Infiniti furnace 59TN6B080C21 96%AFUE, hookup problem with Aprilaire 500 bypass humidifier using Aprilaire digital control w/outside sensor. Humidifier turns water on but the problem is the furnace blower fan doesn't & we get a rapid clicking sound from Aprilaire digital control. Will adding a air sensor switch Aprilaire part # 4592 correct this problem. We were told it would with a wiring change from Aprilaire control to furnace. We really don't want to fool with the Carrier thermostat controller. How do we hookup to work? Test & Reset turns on water but not the fan. Thanks

Comment: Did you pay to have this installed? If so I would think they would come back to make it work.

Comment: Yes they will. but they aren't sure about how to setup. Everytime someone comes its a different person & I'm beginning to think they aren't well trained on the communicating thermostat. So I am waiting for a call back.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an Aprilaire humidifier. Everything thing is controlled by a Honeywell Prestige wifi thermostat with redlink.  I'm out of town so I can't look up the model number. If the Carrier thermostat isn't capable of humidity control, the Honeywell thermostat stat with the RedLink IAQ kit is less than $300. Otherwise you will have to integrate the separate Aprilaire controller.

Regardless it sounds like you paid for a functioning system. Keep on the installer to make it right.